# Get stored procedure parameters by either C# or SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

I was hoping to find an easy way to get a parameter list of a stored procedures parameters. If the procedure has 3 paramaters, I want a list like this:

**param1

param2

param3**

It would be best to be able to do this in C# Code, but SQL would suffice as well. Ideas?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
select * from information_schema.parameters
where specific_name='your_procedure_name'
```

Also refer this post to know more methods
https://exploresql.com/2016/10/14/different-methods-to-get-parameter-list-of-a-stored-procedure/

Answer (score 66):

For SQL Server this should work.

```
private void ListParms()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my sql connection string");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc name", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
    foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(p.ParameterName);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I added this in my foreach:                 if (p.ParameterName == "@RETURN_VALUE") continue;

Answer (score 10):

You can do this without ever touching SqlConnection, which I find is a bonus.

This uses the [`SqlServer.Management.Smo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724.aspx) namespace, so you need a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk`, and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` in your project.

Then use the following code:

```
Server srv = new Server("serverNameHere");
srv.ConnectionContext.AutoDisconnectMode = AutoDisconnectMode.NoAutoDisconnect;
srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false; //if using username/password
srv.ConnectionContext.Login = "username";
srv.ConnectionContext.Password = "password";
srv.ConnectionContext.Connect();

Database db = srv.Databases["databaseNameHere"];

foreach(StoredProcedure sp in db.StoredProcedures)
{
    foreach(var param in sp.Parameters)
    {
        string paramName = param.Name;
        var dataType = param.DataType;
        object defaultValue = param.DefaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found these assemblies here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

Answer (score 9):

If you're familiar with Enterprise Library, there's a good method which allows to [DiscoverParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database.discoverparameters(PandP.31).aspx), using the [Data Access Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649598.aspx).

```
DbCommand command = new DbCommand();
command.CommandText = @"myStoredProc";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Database database = new SqlDatabase(myConnectionString);
database.DiscoverParameters(command);
// ...
```

Some links that might help:

1. [DiscoverParameters Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database.discoverparameters(v=PandP.31).aspx);
2. [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data(v=PandP.31).aspx).

The above links refers to EntLib 3.1. Depending on the .NET Framework version you're using, you might also consider downloading the correct EntLib version for you following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx).