# C# and Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

How can I pass parameters to a stored procedure dynamically using C#?

For example I have a table called `Person` which has columns `Name`, `City`, `Zipcode` etc.

So the code is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.varchar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.varchar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zipcode", SqlDbType.varchar);
```

Now I am adding two more columns, let's say `State` and `Country`.

So code will now be:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.varchar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.varchar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zipcode", SqlDbType.varchar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.varchar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.varchar);
```

Is there any better way to do things?

***Edited:***

after searching online i come up with following solution

**behind aspx.cs file:**

Dictionary dicPersonHash = new Dictionary();

```
    dicPersonHash .Add("@Name", txtName.Text);
    dicPersonHash .Add("@City", txtCity.Text);
    dicPersonHash .Add("@Zipcode", txtZipcode.Text);
    dicPersonHash .Add("@State", txtState.Text);
    dicPersonHash .Add("@Country", txtName.Text);
    dicPersonHash.Add("@returnID", null);
    dicPersonHash .Add("mode", "Insert");
    dicPersonHash .Add("spName", "ManagePerson");
```

and have class called clsDataAccess.cs and has method called ManageData

```
public int ManageData(Dictionary<string, object> dicDataHash)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] excludeKeyHash = { "mode", "spName" };
        try
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(dicDataHash["spName"].ToString(), cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dicDataHash)
            {
                if (!excludeKeyHash.Contains(kvp.Key))
                {
                    if (kvp.Key == "@returnID")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (dicDataHash["mode"] == "Insert")
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@returnID"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            i = -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
        return i;
    }
```

what about these? is any better way to do these? please give me comment/suggestion on these

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: how to dynamic get the parameters is explaind here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038364/get-stored-procedure-parameters-by-either-c-sharp-or-sql

Comment: Do you have to use stored proc's? Maybe take a look at ORM's NHibernate and EF

Comment: i search online and come up with solution