# @args is not a parameter for procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-functions

I am trying to call a stored procedure with a string as parameter (`VARCHAR (MAX)`) but again and again it tells my `@args` parameter is not when it certainly is. This is my test procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'TEST', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
    DROP PROCEDURE TEST;  
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (@args varchar (max)) AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(...);'
    , @params = N'@args varchar(max)'
    , @args = @args
WITH RESULT SETS ((...));
RETURN 0;
END
```

If I call it from management studio, it works:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH
EXEC dbo.TEST @args = 'long string'
GO
```

but not through C#

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection test!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop");

    string ConnectionString = "...";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand    cmd  = new SqlCommand("TEST");
    SqlDataReader rdr  = null;

    string args = "very long string";

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection  = conn;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@args", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = args;
    conn.Open();

    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); } // @args is not a parameter for TEST Procedure
    catch (SqlException ex)
```

I am not reusing any parameter which is just a varchar(max). Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to change this line `cmd.Parameters.Add("@args", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = args;` to `cmd.Parameters.Add("@args", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = args;`

Comment: Unfortunately, same result. I understand -1 tells C# to set args as a varchar(max). What is the difference if I remove it?

Comment: Theoretically your code looks OK. Even with it, it should have worked and you are right. Maybe you are not connected to the right database then, on your solution?

Comment: Assuming you are connected to the correct database what you have looks ok, what is the exact error message?

Comment: The message says: 
Index #0
Message: @args ist kein Parameter für die TEST-Prozedur. (@args is not a parameter for the TEST procedure.)
LineNumber: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure: TEST

By the way, I know I am connected to the right DB because the error rises when I change the param type. Everything is ok when I sum 2 ints for example.

Comment: Does command text of "dbo.TEST" make a difference? As a sanity check drop the proc & run the code and see if you get a cannot find procedure error.

Comment: What are the arguments in the stored procedure?

Comment: @mjwills Same error when renaming the variable. What is interesting is what happens after dropping the procedure as suggested by Alex K, I get the "cannot find procedure error" but C# still tells that args (or bob) is not a parameter, so I infer the error is in C# but where?

Comment: @jdweng a long string with params and settings for the R script

Comment: I get the "cannot find procedure error" but C# still tells that args (or bob) is not a parameter, so I infer the error is in C# but where? -> Can you show us screenshots of both those errors (cannot find procedure and args is not a parameter) when you delete the stored proc?

Comment: Yes. In fact, that's part of the R script, so it shouldn't affect.

Comment: Try running the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).,  There may be an error in the query.  The error messages are much better in SSMS than VS,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the error which was extremely silly.

Short answer: added the SQL `USE` statement before dropping and creating the proc.

```
USE myDB;
GO
```

Long answer: It turns out I have 2 DBs and I was creating the SP in master but I had another procedure in my testing DB. So although I deleted the SP, there was another one in the other DB with the same name but different parameters, hence the error. As I could not understand why `@args` was incorrect, I listed the SP params (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3038470/2846161, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3038530/2846161) and it turned out that the procedure was listed even being deleted, therefore it was replicated.