# Get declared parameters Data type and add the parameters dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

I'm having a problem in retrieving declared parameters in SQL query in C#.

Here is my SQL query in SQL server.

```
Declare @param1 int =1
Declare @param2 varhar(255)='Admin'

SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE role=@param2 AND id=@param1`
```

The query is executing successfully on SQL server.

I'd like to use C# to get all declared parameters and Data types. In this case:

```
PARAMETER    DATA TYPE
@param1      int
@param2.     Varchar
```

Finally, I'd like to assign the values of the parameters dynamically using a textbox.

Comment: Your T-SQL batch has local variables, not  parameters. It would be necessary to parse the batch text to get the data types. It would be much easier if you encapsulate the T-SQL code in a stored procedure so the parameter names and types are easily discoverable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038364/get-stored-procedure-parameters-by-either-c-sharp-or-sql).

Comment: Seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a batch that uses local variables which are set using constants.  You might think of them as "parameters" but they are not. I think you just need to parameterize the sql statement in your application.