# How can I retrieve parameters from SQL query using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I need help in retrieving parameters in SQL query (not stored procedure) and their data types in C#.
Here is a sample query.

```
Declare @param1 int
Declare @param2 varchar(255)

Select * 
from tablenanme 
where col1 = @param1 and col2 = @param2
```

How can I also assign these values dynamically in C#

I've tried but I can really figure it out

Comment: Where is your C# code?  What attempt have you made and what specifically didn't work?  What do you mean by *retrieve* parameters?  Do you mean that you're trying to *add* parameters to your query?  Please clarify the question.

Comment: I'm sure I saw this question the other day...

Comment: I did... How is this different from your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69695780/2029983)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# and SQL get declared parameters Data type and add the parameters dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69695780/c-sharp-and-sql-get-declared-parameters-data-type-and-add-the-parameters-dynamic) Don't repost the same question again

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare local variables in the batch. Instead, add parameters/values to the command object:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("Select * from tablenanme where col1=@param1 and col2=@param2", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = col1Value;
command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = co2Value;
```